# How do I maintain session across requests in django if I'm using cache / db based session?

Tags: python, django, session, cookies

I'm implementing a in-memory cache-based session in django: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/sessions/#using-cached-sessions

```
        session_store = SessionStore()
        session_store['key'] = value
        session_store.create()
```

but i found that even though the data does persist in memory across multiple requests, but it wont set the session_key in the cookie. Is the intended usage to just pass the key to client and have them send back as a param?

right now im manually setting and retrieving the cookie  (as request.session['session_key'] doesnt work for me)

CREATE

```
            response = Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
            response.set_cookie('session_key', session.session_key)
```

RETRIEVE

```
            session_key = request.COOKIES['session_key']
```

Comment: The default name for the session cookie is "sessionid" have you changed this?

Comment: @lain where can i set it? i was assuming the sessionstore will handle that for me

Comment: The session middleware will set the cookie when `request.session` is modified. You wouldn't usually use a `SessionStore` directly

Comment: @IainShelvington thx! I found that if i mutate SessionStore(), it wont generate a `sessionid` in cookie. i moved the code about session from serializer to view and use `request.session` to load and save, now it works fine. I find the documentation not clear enough that they will not be doing the same.